# How do I animate the radius filling up along curve?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

This is a burger with mayo on it.
[image]
I want to simulate someone squeezing out this mayo onto the bread. I already achieved the finished result using a spline parameter and float curve.
[image]
However now I want it to animate. The desired result would be starting with nothing on the bread and it being squeezed out. I can animate a something travelling along the curve. I'm just not sure how to get the mayo to fill up along it's own curve. Is this easily achievable in geo nodes?

Comment: just use trim curve and animate the values. If you cannot do that, pls provide blend file so we don't have to rebuild it manually. thx.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: @yojimboyd you can answer your own question now you have a solution, it may help others otherwise your question is likely to be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use trim curve and animate the values